# Hibernate Criteria compare objects

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

in HQL i can silpy comapre objects

```
From Entity e WHERE e=:lookingforentity
```

and hibernate automatically compares the id

with criteria i can only compare properties

```
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("id", lookingforentityid));
```

is it possible with criteria to filter by an object list?

this is not a real problem but would make the code more readable

in my specific case i want to fetch all entities which are not contained in a list:

```
List<Entit> e;
missingCrit.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in(??, e)))
```

and i don't like to create a list with the id's first

i already tried

```
List<Entity> entitylist = xxx;
Criteria missing = session.createCriteria(Entity.class, "e");
missing.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("e", entitylist )));
```

this results in

```
could not resolve property: e of: Entity
```

Comment: what happens when you try it?

Comment: i cannot try because i don't know what to fill in at Restrictions.in(??, e)

Comment: Put the alias of the entity you want to compare. If it doesn' have one, then assign one: `session.createCriteria(Entit.class, "e")`.

Comment: when i try crit.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("e", entitylist))); i get "could not resolve property: e of: xxx.Entity"

Comment: Then you have your answer: it doesn't work. Use IDs.

Comment: mh the're hating my answer =( ... but i hate answers too which say: it's impossible